# How to convert microsoft word para/range to html?

Tags: html, ms-word

I am working a project which has requirement to convert specific paragraphs in word document to HTML. I will have the range object of para or paras , from that range I can get WordOpenXML, I want to convert that to HTML. ( it should not have the html, head, body tags as it is not full document but just a small html chunk )

I saw Eric White's open XML articles, he did great articles on this topic and power tools for openxml has html converter which converts entire document to html, my requirement is to convert a specific para or range to HTML. Can any one guide me in right direction.

For example, If a word document has

```
This is para1.

This is para2.

This is para3.
```

My requirement is to convert para2, which is available with me as para object. So, basically I am looking to write a function like

```
public string WordOpenXMLToHtml( string sWordOpenXML) {
    // do the transformation
    return sHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the HtmlConverter object. More info here [Transforming Open XML WordprocessingML to XHTML Using the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff628051.aspx)